# How to remove index.php in codeigniter's path?

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

I want to remove "Index.php" from every url of the project. I follow many instruction of previous asked question. But i am unable to solve the issue.
I am unable to find the actual .htaccess file. 
My Codeigniter version is "3.0.6"
.htaccess file contain this

```html
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

[image]

**Please guide me. If any information is missing in this question please let me know. I am new in Codeigniter.**

Comment: Have a look here https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter but if your also using wamp enable mod rewrite don't touch the htaccess in the application folder.

Comment: there is too many file present in the above link... Can you guide me which file should i use. ?

Comment: @wolfgang1983 thanks for helping me fix this issue

Answer (score 3):

you only need to create the .htaccess file on the same level as your index

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: In which file i put all this? 
Can you explain me how does it work...?

Comment: It works fine.. @elddenmedio Please Explain all the keyword used in the .htaccess file. How its work?

Comment: `RewriteEngine On` - activate the rewrite mode `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` - if the file with the specified name in the browser doesn't exist, or the directory in the browser doesn't exist then procede to the rewrite rule below `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]` - ignore the url and the parameter $1 will be executed